# Create a sequence for a specific element in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

im trying to create a function that assign a number to an xml element by sequence. Let me give you an example. My desired output xml is this:

```
             <Item>
                <ZDoc>
                    <seq>1</seq>
                </ZDoc>
                <ZDoc>
                    <seq>2</seq>
                </ZDoc>
                <TDoc>
                    <seq>1</seq>
                </TDoc>
                <TDoc>
                    <seq>2</seq>
                </TDoc>
            </Item>
            <Item>
                <ZDoc>
                    <seq>1</seq>
                </ZDoc>
                <ZDoc>
                    <seq>2</seq>
                </ZDoc>
                <TDoc>
                    <seq>1</seq>
                </TDoc>
                <TDoc>
                    <seq>2</seq>
                </TDoc>
            </Item>
```

I have created this function:

```
<xsl:template name="my_func()">
    <xsl:param name="id_name" select="''"/> 
    <!-- Count elements -->
    <xsl:variable name="seq" select="count(//*[local-name() = $global-id]) + 1"/>
    <!-- Output the generated sequence number -->
    <xsl:value-of select="$seq"/>
</xsl:template>
```

But it returns only sequenceNumber 1. Also as you see the id_name is the node name like TDoc and ZDoc.
The output is this:

```
<Item>
                <ZDoc>
                    <seq>1</seq>
                </ZDoc>
                <ZDoc>
                    <seq>2</seq>
                </ZDoc>
                <TDoc>
                    <seq>1</seq>
                </TDoc>
                <TDoc>
                    <seq>1</seq>
                </TDoc>
            </Item>
            <Item>
                <ZDoc>
                    <seq>1</seq>
                </ZDoc>
                <ZDoc>
                    <seq>1</seq>
                </ZDoc>
                <TDoc>
                    <seq>1</seq>
                </TDoc>
                <TDoc>
                    <seq>1</seq>
                </TDoc>
            </Item>
```

I tried another approach which seemed to work better but again it begins the count from 2 in the last element

```
<xsl:template name="my_func()">
    <xsl:param name="id" select="()"/>
    <xsl:variable name="auto_number" as="xs:integer" select="position() "/> 
    <xsl:sequence select="xs:integer($auto_number)"/>
</xsl:template>
```

but know the output is this:

```
<Item>
                <ZDoc>
                    <seq>1</seq>
                </ZDoc>
                <ZDoc>
                    <seq>2</seq>
                </ZDoc>
                <TDoc>
                    <seq>2</seq>
                </TDoc>
                <TDoc>
                    <seq>3</seq>
                </TDoc>
            </Item>
            <Item>
                <ZDoc>
                    <seq>1</seq>
                </ZDoc>
                <ZDoc>
                    <seq>2</seq>
                </ZDoc>
                <TDoc>
                    <seq>2</seq>
                </TDoc>
                <TDoc>
                    <seq>3</seq>
                </TDoc>
            </Item>
                                     

                                    <seq>                             
                                        <xsl:call-template 
                                             name="my_func">
                                            <xsl:with-param name="id" 
                                             select="'TDoc'" as="item()"/>
                                        </xsl:call-template>
                                    </seq>
```

What im missing?? Any ideas??

Comment: Please share your source xml as well.

Comment: this is my source xml @SiebeJongebloed

Comment: Ah sorry..my source xml is really huge

Answer (score 1):

To count nodes, I'd suggest using [`xsl:number`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#number).

Also you haven't created a function, you've created a named template. In XSLT 2.0+, there are actual functions (`xsl:function`) so it's important to get the terminology correct.

I'm not sure what version of XSLT you're using, so here's a 1.0 example...

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="ZDoc|TDoc">
        <xsl:copy>
            <seq><xsl:call-template name="get_seq"/></seq>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template name="get_seq">
        <xsl:variable name="to_count" select="name()"/>
        <xsl:number from="Item" count="*[name()=$to_count]"/>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```